How to Send Emails to Secondary Email Address in Dynamics CRM Customer service module Based on Case Creation Email?
We have a case management system in Dynamics 365 where we want to maintain a unique contact for each customer. However, we're facing an issue where Dynamics 365 does not allow us to use the secondary email address in the "To" field when sending emails via a workflow using the "Send Email" trigger.
Our requirement is to send all communications, including automated communications, based on the email address through which the case was created:
If a case is raised via the primary email address, then all communications should go to the primary email.
If the incoming email address is a secondary email address, then all communications, including automated communications, should be sent to the secondary email.
I am new to dynamics. Any help will be great!!
